# How can I create a OffScreen Buffer with Image Texture Data

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I want to create a offscreen buffer with image loaded to it. When user do the changes have to been done in the texture which is in the Offscreen Buffer.

Comment: How is what you're asking for different from just a texture? Any texture you create is "offscreen". Only the textures of drawables get put on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UIGraphicsImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer) to draw into an offscreen context and get back a UIImage.  Its like an other graphics context, so all of the Coregraphics and UIKit drawing methods work inside UIGraphicsImageRenderer.